# Add button inside AndroidXMapFragment in here maps

Tags: here-api

I'm using the here android SDK and started with the BasicMapSolution tutorial.
Now I want to add buttons on top of the map (zoom in/zoom out/center view to my position).
Unfortunately I did not figure out how to do it.
I tried adding a button in activity_main.xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Map Fragment embedded with the map object -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|top"
            android:text="Demo Button"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the button is not shown in the app. Can anyone help please. Just to make it clear, I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to do a zoom using 2 finger tap ? https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-gestures.html
Map gesture customisation can also be done. In case adding zoom controls is requirement then you can add a map marker object of unknown type, and pass zoom in min max range on its listener in premium SDK. As of now, traditional zoom in/zoom button add on controls are not available. you can refer below API documentation to check for mapobject and zoom range in details.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/api_reference_java/index.html

Also refer to our github example for map marker objects and gestures that are already available >

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/map-objects/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/map/objects/MapFragmentView.java